# Can I pass an integer to `access_ok()` as it's second argument?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, userspace

In *LDD3*'s example, `access_ok()` is placed at the beginning of `ioctl` method of a kernel module to check whether a pointer passed from userspace is valid. It is correct when userspace application calls `ioctl()` system call, and passes it an address of a variable. In some cases, however, `ioctl()` system call is invoked with a value instead of a pointer as third argument and finally the second argument of `access_ok()` in kernel module.

I've tried to pass an integer as `access_ok()`'s second argument and it works fine. No error was reported. But I don't very sure that is this usage correct?

For example, if I invoke `ioctl()` in userspace with it's third argument to be '3'. Then, in `ioctl()` method of `struct file_operations`, `access_ok()` will receive `3` as it's second argument. Because the `access_ok()` expects a pointer, so it translates `3` to be a userspace pointer. Obversely, it's wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `access_ok`'s check is rough. Description of the function (in the source file) say:

> Note that, depending on architecture, this function probably just
>   checks that the pointer is in the user space range - after calling
>   this function, memory access functions may still return -EFAULT.

E.g., according to source `arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h`, on x86 `access_ok` just checks that given address points to the *lower* area (because kernel besides in the upper area). So, it returns `true` for address equal to `3`.

It is `copy_from_user`/`copy_to_user` who return a final verdict about user memory accessibility.

Comment: So, what will happen if I pass a very big value which can be translated as a kernel address? In this situation, will `access_ok()` return false? or, even, kernel panic? What's more, on some architectures, `access_ok()` will simply return 1 and do nothing more. but on X86, what's done than simply return 1?

Comment: If you pass kernel adress to `access_ok`, it will return false.

Answer (score 0):

Userspace programs can give you any random value as a pointer, so `access_ok()` must be able to handle any random value.
So it is definitely OK to call `access_ok()` with a non-pointer value.

However, unless you are actually going to try to access that memory location, calling `access_ok()` is utterly pointless.
(For that matter, you should, if possible, avoid `access_ok()` and just check the actual userspace accesses (`get_user()` etc.) for errors.)